# TSQL - Mapping Parent/Child Hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, hierarchy

> Sample Data:

```
DECLARE @Hierarchy TABLE
    (
        [ParentId] INT
      , [ChildId]  INT
    ) ;

INSERT INTO @Hierarchy
VALUES
    ( 1, 2 )
  , ( 1, 3 )
  , ( 2, 4 )
  , ( 3, 5 )
  , ( 4, 3 )
  , ( 4, 6 )
  , ( 5, 6 )
  , ( 7, 3 ) ;
```

> Current Query:

```
; WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT  [ParentId]
              , [ChildId]
              , 1 AS [Level]
              , CONCAT ( CAST ( [ParentId] AS VARCHAR(MAX) ), '.', CAST ( [ChildId] AS VARCHAR(MAX) ) )  AS [Path]
        FROM    @Hierarchy
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  [C].[ParentId]
              , [T].[ChildId]
              , [C].[Level] + 1
              , CAST ( [C].[Path] + '.' + CAST([T].[ChildId] AS VARCHAR(MAX) ) AS VARCHAR(MAX) )
        FROM    CTE AS [C]
        JOIN    @Hierarchy AS [T]
        ON      [C].[ChildId] = [T].[ParentId]
    )
SELECT      *
FROM        CTE
ORDER BY    [ParentId]
          , [Level]
          , [ChildId] ;
```

> Goal:

1. distinctly group levels of shared "path" together
2. find the shallowest and the deepest levels of the shared "path"

> Expected Output:

NOTICE: the records with Orange highlight at the end are manually inserted to show what I'm expecting, but haven't figure out yet.

[image]

Group: Basically a "dense rank" of each "groups" of nodes that follow the same path. I think if you look at the values of Group in the above image and relate it to Level and Path field's data, it'll make more sense.

IsShallowest: 1st level (I can see that now that someone brought it up). Just need to figure out how to derive those missing (repeating) records

IsDeepest: max level within the group.

Think IsShallowest and IsDeepest is easy to figure out once "Group" logic is figured out and adding missing (repeated) records.

Comment: what is "Group" ?

Comment: ; Interesting that `IsShallowest` is almost, but not always, correlated with `Level = 1`. ; I wonder what makes `1.2.4.6` shallowest. ;

Comment: How does ChildId 3 get three ParentIds (1, 4, 7)?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, as much as I understand the poor description, this is not a tree Hierarchy structure but a Many-To-Many structure. You can notice that chaildid 3 has these three ParentIds (1, 4, 7) in the source table. This data seems like best fit to Graph Modeling and not to relational Modeling. It should probably work better if the database will be redesign in SQL Server 2019 using graph feature.

Comment: @007,  (1) please explain what is the meaning of the row that you manually inserted in the expected result and how to come to this row out of the source data. I find not logic in this row at this time. Why this rows was added?!? (2) Please explain the logic behind the groups - go row by row and explain how and why you got this specific value as the group value

Comment: I have a full solution for you including the Groups and ISshallowest and Isdeepest (took me awhile to get where these columns got their value from, since you did not provide any logic to the expected result). **The only thing I still do not understand is where the extra row came from?!?** Why you manually inserted another rows in the expected result?!?

Comment: If your expected result missing another extra row for group 3 with the [Path] value 1.2 then I get where you got the extra row for the group 5. As I see it, you are missing a row in the expected result or you have extra row with no logic (that I understood) behind it. My Guess is that you simply miss one more extra row for group 3.

Comment: @alexm: Updated OP. HABO: That was an oversight on my part - updated OP. AlwaysLearning: Ronen Ariely is right in his explanation. Ronen Ariely: The manually inserted rows are basically repeating rows that were already part of a diff group.. for example, look at the path of the manually inserted rows for 1.2 and 1.2.4, you will notice that it was already part of Group = 1's. from 1.2.4.. the branch split into two separate paths - 1.2.4.3 vs 1.2.4.6. So to get level 1 and 2 for 2nd path, I have to someone repeat the shared path for the subsequent groups.

Comment: @RonenAriely, as for the logic for Groups, I've rearranged the output and updated the screenshot in OP. Basically, a (distinctly numbered) group represents all nodes' records in one path. Not sure if this is any clearer now, but if updated screenshot still confuses, let me know. Thank you

Comment: It looks like you want to start with the deepest nodes, e.g. `7.3.5.6`, and assign a `Group` to each, then truncate the tail end back up the `Path` (`7.3.5`, `7.3`), but not quite to the root, i.e. `7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this solution. It provide the requested solution except adding the extra row which more information is needed

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  
        [ParentId]
        , [ChildId]
        , 1 AS [Level]
        , CONCAT ( CAST ( [ParentId] AS VARCHAR(MAX) ), '.', CAST ( [ChildId] AS VARCHAR(MAX) ) )  AS [Path]
        , MyGroup1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [ParentId])
        , MyGroup2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [ParentId])
    FROM Hierarchy
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  
        [C].[ParentId]
        , [T].[ChildId]
        , [C].[Level] + 1
        , CAST ( [C].[Path] + '.' + CAST([T].[ChildId] AS VARCHAR(MAX) ) AS VARCHAR(MAX) )
        , MyGroup1 = C.MyGroup1
        , MyGroup2 = [C].[MyGroup1] + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [T].[ParentId]) - 1
    FROM CTE AS [C]
    JOIN Hierarchy AS [T] ON [C].[ChildId] = [T].[ParentId]
)
, MyCTE2 as (
    SELECT
        [ParentId]
        , [ChildId]
        , [Level]
        , [Path]
        -- un-comment bellow 2 rows to see the logic
        --, MyGroup1
        --, MyGroup2
        , MyGroup = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MyGroup1, MyGroup2)
    FROM CTE
),
MyCTE3 as (
    SELECT
        [ParentId]
        , [ChildId]
        , [Level]
        , [Path]
        , MyGroup 
        , shallowest = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MyGroup ORDER BY [Path]) 
        , deepest = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MyGroup ORDER BY [Path] DESC) 
    FROM MyCTE2
)
SELECT
    [ParentId]
    , [ChildId]
    , [Level]
    , [Path]
    , MyGroup 
    , ISshallowest = CASE WHEN shallowest = 1 then 1 else 0 END
    , Isdeepest = CASE WHEN deepest = 1 then 1 else 0 END
FROM MyCTE3
ORDER BY
    --[Path]
    [ParentId]
    , [Level]
    , [ChildId];
```

Comment: this is amazing!! Thank you for your help, really appreciate it. It's going to take me some time to figure out what's going in the code so I can incorporate it in my production scenario, but output looks on point. As for the manually inserted records, I've updated the OP and added comment there. Please let me know if it's still confusing. Cheers mate!